# Как заменить содержимое контейнера на страницу url

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel

При нажатии на ссылку открывается новое окно. как открыть эту страницу в div или еще как (можно поверх ) . 
Сайт написан на laravel

Скрипт открывает новое окно, а как открыть на той же странице ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<script>
function showInstructions(url) {
    width = screen.availWidth;
    height = screen.availHeight;
    window.open(url,'_blank',"height="+height+",width="+width+", toolbar=no, top=0,left=0,location=no,menubar=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes,resizable=no");

    runner();
}

function runner()
{
    url = localStorage.getItem('redirect_url');
    if(url) {
      localStorage.clear();
       window.location = url;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
          runner();
    }, 500);

}
</script>
```

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону JQueryUI... там точно есть то что вам нужно

Answer (score 0):

```
const cb = function () {
  const popup = document.createElement('div');

  popup.id = 'instructions-popup';
  popup.style.position = 'fixed';
  popup.style.width = '80%';
  popup.style.height = '80%';
  popup.style.top = '10%';
  popup.style.left = '10%';
  popup.innerHTML = this.response;

  document.body.appendChild(popup);
};

const showInstructionsPopup = (url) => {
  const popup = document.getElementById('instructions-popup');

  if (popup) {
    popup.remove();
  }

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.addEventListener('load', cb);
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();
};
```